# How I can deploy a site built with a gulp?

Tags: git, web, gulp

help solve the problem: there is a project which I am building through gulp. There are three folders in total, one of them is called app where the site is built. At the moment, all folders and files are uploaded to the git, but I need to deploy the project to the server in the public_html folder. I do not understand how this can be done. I came to the decision to divide into two repositories - one of which will be with the built site and I will deploy it to the root of the public_html folder, but now I don’t know how to connect these two repositories to each other so that after building the site it would go to the second repository.

Comment: I think it’s a good idea to create a symlink to the app folder

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you just looking for a gulp ftp plugin?  If so, I like `vinyl-ftp`.